# A tick box "same as home/primary address" when submitting Event/Contribution from Admin using paypal pro. way to fix it?

Tags: addresses, paypal

[image]
Although selected contact has an address in his profile (But No Billing address). It would be useful to have a tick box saying "same as home/primary address", admin doesn't need to type in all the info again. Can anyone suggest how to do it in a quick way?

Comment: CiviCRM thinks you need a street address because some credit card companies require it; if your CC processor is one of those (I've never hit one myself), then omitting the values might fail submission.

Comment: Thanks. But my point is how to prefill the address & name info in the billing block. As we can see from the form street address is mandatory filed for paypal pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you on - I just checked a 4.6.6 site & a contact with a home address (only) is getting the prefill - although if you change processor that form is not prefilling. (there is an open ticket about that )

Comment: Thanks Eileen, I am on 4.6.6. and you are correct it prefills the name &  address data if I go from person's profile > Contribution > Submit Credit card contribution. it works, Even that person only has home/primary address & NO billing address.
However it does not work if used the link from the left CREATE NEW> Contribution> Contribution (credit Card). Bug may be!!??

Comment: can you also please post the link of that open ticket you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the requirement of those fields using `hook_civicrm_buildForm()` - see [CiviCRM hook reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference)

Here's [an example from a couple of years ago](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27856.0), although this was written for user-facing forms:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().
 */
function example_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  switch ($formName) {
    case 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main':
      $fields_not_required = array(
        'billing_first_name',
        'billing_middle_name',
        'billing_last_name',
        'billing_street_address-5',
        'billing_city-5',
        'billing_state_province_id-5',
        'billing_postal_code-5',
        'billing_country_id-5',
      );
      foreach ($fields_not_required as $field) {
        $form->_paymentFields[$field]['is_required'] = FALSE;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, if my question was not clear. I am not trying to avoid entering the address data, rather want to prefill from the existing address of contact profile.

Comment: The code above doesn't do what you want then, but perhaps you could build on it to pre-fill the data as you desire instead of changing the field's required setting.